# Tire compatibility for hybrid cruiser

Tags: tire

I have a 28" Schwinn Yorkshire 700c hybrid cruiser. I got it since it was the only one in my price range but the problem is the tires are too slim for me and I'm used to much wider ones, so I was wondering what kind of wide tires are compatible with it?

Comment: Why do you think the tire width is a problem? What size tires did it ship with?

Comment: Any 700c (ISO 622) tire will fit, so long as the width is not too weird and the tread design is not too wild.  This includes "29 inch" tires and a subset of "28 inch" tires.  (But "27 inch" tires won't fit -- they're too big.)

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you posted a picture of your current setup in order to see how much clearance you have, but, any 700c or 29" tire will work provided it's not too wide to fit in your frame. Your local bike shop should have a wide assortment of tires that are suitable.